# How to join tables using a primary key in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

There are two tables, emp and dept. And both tables has deptno as a primary key. I want to display details about deptno between 10 and 20 with ename.

For example: loc is in dept table: with sal column :

```
select ename,sal,loc,deptno from emp,dept
where sal between 1000 and 2000 and emp.deptno=dept.deptno;
```

In this query I want to replace sal with deptno but giving error.

Comment: Please edit into your question the error you are getting.

Comment: For reference, this question was heavily downvoted because: (a) not enough effort was spent prior to asking; (b) the post contained txtspk - often readers will think that words such as "are" should not be too much trouble to write; (c) the first version of the post appeared to ask the reader to do the work, (d) the problem is still not clear (it mentions an error but doesn't mention _what_ error), (e) the title contained no detail, just obscene levels of begging.

Comment: For your next question, make sure it is clear you have made a solid effort first, and then ensure all of the above points are rectified.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume

- Table 1 is dept
- Table 2 is emp
- `dept` table has `deptno` as primary key and some other columns
- `emp` table has columns `ename` and `deptno` where `deptno` is foreign key to `deptno` column of `dept` table

This is a SQL query to select `deptno` and `ename` of the records having `deptno` between 10 and 20 :

```
SELECT 
    dept.deptno, emp.ename 
FROM 
    dept 
JOIN 
    emp ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno 
WHERE 
    dept.deptno BETWEEN 10 and 20;
```

Comment: I have to join both of the table

Comment: Again showing column ambiguously defined . thanks bro from again and again helping me .now help me again plz

Comment: SELECT 
   d.deptno, e.ename 
FROM 
    dept d
JOIN 
    emp e ON d.deptno = e.deptno 
WHERE 
    d.deptno BETWEEN 10 and 20;

Comment: I have updated the answer by specifying absolute column names in SELECT section.Please check.